# Transform GWT-Project to Multi-Module Project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jar, maven-module

I am trying to transform a working single GWT-Project into several Maven-Modules.
New structure should look like this:

```
Project
|- pom.xml
|- Project-Common(only Common-Classes)
|--- pom.xml
|--- Packaging: jar
|- Project-War(includes *gwt.xml)
|--- pom.xml
|--- Packaging: war
```

My files look like this(many dependencies, I think i removed the unnecessary to make my problem more clear)
Project pom.xml:

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Project - Modules</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<modules>
    <module>/project-war</module>
    <module>/project-common</module>
</modules>
```

Project-Common pom.xml:

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Project - Common</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.koraktor</groupId>
          <artifactId>mavanagaiata</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>load-git-branch</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>commit</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <dirtyFlag>*</dirtyFlag>
                <gitDir>../../.git</gitDir>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

Project-War pom.xml:

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>project-war</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Project - WAR</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>   

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>/test.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.project.modules.Test</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <id>VerifyRequestFactoryInterfaces</id>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-cp</argument>
                            <classpath />
                            <argument>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ValidationTool</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                            <argument>com.project.factorys.TestRequestFactory</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <directory>gwt-unitCache/**</directory>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.koraktor</groupId>
          <artifactId>mavanagaiata</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>load-git-branch</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>commit</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <dirtyFlag>*</dirtyFlag>
                <gitDir>../../.git</gitDir>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The old Project was in my Project-War and I added Project & Project-Common. In this setup the Project builds and I get the "new" Project-War.war .
But when I move a ErrorCode.java from Project-War to Project-Common I get the following Error:

> [INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.project.modules.TestViewImpl'
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in '.../project/project-war/src/main/java/com/project/modules/TestViewImpl.java'
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 20: No source code is available for type com.project.errorcodes.ErrorCode; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]    [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

Comment: Are your common classes are used in your GWT project? If yes, do this project also have a module descriptor and did you inherit in your project war module descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution:

Added a Module in Common-Project

```
<module>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.activity.Activity' />
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.place.Place' />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
 <inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.RequestFactory' />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.cellview.CellView" />
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.logging.Logging' />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.text.Text" />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />

 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.debug.Debug" />

 <source path="shared"/>
</module>
```

any my ErrorCode.java is under Path shared/** .


In Project-War Modules I added `<inherits name="com.project.Common" />` and in pom.xml from Project-War:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <classifier>sources</classifier>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Seems to need dependency with classifier in scope provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your Project-Common doesn't package its sources to be available to the Project-War, so GWT effectively can't find the source for `ErrorCodes` class.

You have to either use the `maven-source-plugin`'s `jar-no-fork` goal in Project-Common to package sources, and then add a second dependency on Project-Common in Project-War with `<classifier>sources</classifier>`; or declare your `src/main/java` as a resource directory to package sources into the Project-Common's JAR.

---

As a side note, Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT isn't a great fit for multi-module projects. I'd advise switching to the [`net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin`](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/) which was designed for multi-module builds from the ground up (disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin, and former maintainer of Mojo's plugin)